# What's the performance impact of having many layers?

Tags: performance, openlayers-3, layer

In my mapping application I load several types of features from web services, and currently I'm putting features from each source in a separate layer. I figured that would make it easier to hide/show all related features without affecting other types. I was wondering how that would affect performance. I could also put all features in one layer, the features have properties that allow me to recognize their type easily. What would be the best approach, putting all features together in one layer or giving each feature type it's own layer?

Comment: What is the number you are talking about?

Comment: So far 4 layers, but that may grow in the future. I'd say about 6 or 7 layers max.

Comment: Oh no, for sure, don't worry about performance. I thought you were talking about ~10k.

Comment: Thanks! that means I can continue along the lines I've set out.